# rewrite cloudfront origin host with lambda@edge, how?

Tags: url-rewriting, amazon-cloudfront, aws-lambda-edge

I see people talking about how to rewrite a URI based on various information. But I'd like to normalize the domain name that is being requested. Here's what I've tried:

```
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    const request = event.Records[0].cf.request;

    if (request.method.toUpperCase() != 'GET') {
        callback(null, request);
        return;
    }

    request.origin = {
        custom: {
            domainName: 'slashdot.org',
            port: 443,
            protocol: 'https',
            path: request.uri
        }
    };
    request.headers.host = {
        "key": "Host",
        "value": request.origin.custom.domainName
    };

    console.log("returning req:", request);

    callback(null, request);
}
```

I was hoping that would pull up the request and that cloudfront would then make a request against my canonicalized domain. (for the example and testing, I'm using slashdot, since it's obvious it isn't **my** content).

Ultimately, I'm trying to canonicalize a request without doing redirects, but instead rewriting the request before hit hits the origin.

Comment: You shouldn't test against anybody else's site, because in addition to the etiquette aspect, they may have scraping protections or other anti-abuse mechanisms in place that cause the site to behave unexpectedly in cases like this.

Comment: Does this not work for you ?

Comment: No, it doesn't work. I haven't been able to rewrite a request.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Oh, neat. I finally figured out how to do this. First, some restrictions:

- With https this only works for domains under your certificate. So I can't use `mydomain.com` and `slashdot.org` unless I'm [CmdrTaco](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rob_Malda). That's fine, my AWS [ACM](https://aws.amazon.com/certificate-manager/) cert includes three domains, one of which is my actual domain. I'll call that **`actualdomain.com`** below.
- This cannot be done on the **viewer request**, only the **origin request**, as [`host` is read-only for the viewer request](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/lambda-requirements-limits.html#lambda-read-only-headers).

Given that, I used "[Example: Using an Origin-Request Trigger to Change From an Amazon S3 Origin to a Custom Origin](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/lambda-examples.html#lambda-examples-content-based-custom-origin-request-trigger)" with some minor modifications. Here's the full Lambda code.

```
'use strict';

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    const request = event.Records[0].cf.request;
    const destDomain = 'actualdomain.com';


    /* Set custom origin fields*/
    request.origin = {
        custom: {
            domainName: destDomain,
            port: 443,
            protocol: 'https',
            path: '',
            sslProtocols: ['TLSv1', 'TLSv1.1', 'TLSv1.2'],
            readTimeout: 5,
            keepaliveTimeout: 5,
            customHeaders: {}
        }
    };
    request.headers['host'] = [{ key: 'host', value: destDomain}];

    callback(null, request);
};
```

So, similar to the example given in the docs, `destDomain` is the actual domain, and any legitimate domain in my certificate is proxied to that dest, without the end user actually seeing `actualdomain.com`.

Comment: The host header cost me 2 hours...Thank you!

Comment: I lost a day on the host header. Thanks so much for sharing this.

Comment: This approach will strip all your original query parameters.

Comment: Did you notice a huge increase in latency with this? Direct request to origin vs request via cloudfront..