# AWS Edge function for dynamic routing not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

I'm having trouble setting up an easy example using Cloudfront@Edge functions for changing the custom origin of a request, while keeping the domain name.

Following this [guide](https://aws.amazon.com/pt/blogs/networking-and-content-delivery/dynamically-route-viewer-requests-to-any-origin-using-lambdaedge/) and this [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50962205/rewrite-cloudfront-origin-host-with-lambdaedge-how) I have the following setup:

- 2 HTTP Load Balancers, each with a lambda function. They return an HTTP page with the Region + all the headers in the body:

  - 1 in US: `custom-us.us-west-1.elb.amazonaws.com`
  - 1 in EU: `custom-eu.eu-central-1.elb.amazonaws.com`
- 1 cloudfront distribution (`mydistr.cloudfront.net`) with 1 origin, as done in the guide. My origin for the default behavior is `custom-us.us-west-1.elb.amazonaws.com`. The cache policy is `Managed-CachingDisabled`.
- 1 cloudfront@edge lambda function (with `origin-request` trigger) with the following code:

```
'use strict';

module.exports.dynamic_routing = (event, context, callback) => {
  const request = event.Records[0].cf.request;  
  const originUSA = "custom-us.us-west-1.elb.amazonaws.com";
  const originEU = "custom-eu.eu-central-1.elb.amazonaws.com";

  var destDomain = originUSA;
 
  const custom_header = request.headers['custom-header-value'];
  if (custom_header && custom_header.value == "DE") {
      destDomain = originEU;
  }
  
  request.origin = {
      custom: {
          domainName: destDomain,
          port: 80,
          protocol: 'http',
          path: request.uri,
          readTimeout: 20,
          keepaliveTimeout: 5,
          customHeaders: {}
      }
  };
  request.headers['host'] = [{ key: 'host', value: destDomain}];
  
  callback(null, request);
};
```

I can correctly navigate to both Load Balancers and see the right content, which proves that the load balancers + respective lambda functions are correctly setup.

If I navigate to `mydistr.cloudfront.net` the "USA" content is shown, which is correct. However, if send a request with Curl/Postman including my `custom-header-value: DE`, I keep seeing the USA info:
[image]

when I expected to have changed the origin.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well...the solution was quite simple.

All the headers are arrays and thus the problem was here: `custom_header.value == "DE"` where it should in fact be `custom_header[0].value == "DE"`.